# ubuntu 20.04 lts, mysql CPU load 100%

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache, ec2

**RU**:
Всем привет. подскажите, куда копать?
Есть EC2 Instance, на нем поднят LAMP Stack

Mysql, по истечению 3-4 дней после очередного ребута, начинает кушать весть CPU в 100%
БД очень маленькая, меньше мегабайта. Куда смотреть?

```
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper
```

Скрин до ребута ниже. Спасибо!!

**ENG**:
I create AWS EC2 instance, t2.medium, install LAMP Stack. Then, succesfuly restore mysql.dump, configure apache2 + php.

And 3-4 days after creating instance, mysql process use 100% of my CPU. Can you help me please? If i reboot EC2, everything start normal and CPU load is minimal

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

BEFORE reboot
[image: Screenshot]

UPD: error.log

```
2021-08-25T08:28:47.051298Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2021-08-25T08:28:47.054673Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-08-25T08:28:47.054719Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2021-08-25T08:28:47.056009Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2021-08-25T08:28:47.056026Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2021-08-25T08:28:47.056137Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2021-08-25T08:28:47.077015Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210825  8:28:47
2021-08-25T08:28:47.144311Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2021-08-25T08:28:47.144515Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.35'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский... И если mysql 100% значит смотрите логи запросов - с ними проблема

Comment: Привет. Сори, сделал на русском. Вы не подскажите, как правильно смотреть логи запросов?

Comment: Смотрите, откуда столько потоков, каким они заняты и почему не закрываются, если они idle.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась.

Ошибка заключалась в том, что в базе висело около 50 штук запросов:

```
SELECT sys_scheduler.*, MAX(sys_scheduler_log.created) AS created FROM
sys_scheduler LEFT OUTER JOI
```

и все в состоянии Sending data.
Все это висело по той причине, что были выданы неправильные права на необходимые скрипты внутри корня сайта. Сначала я выдал права, затем внутри mysql сделал:

```
delete from sys_scheduler_log
```

Но мой случай уникальный, потому, если у кого-то возникнет такое же, проверяйте скрипты и права на них.